Is there anything that can be done to make List Views update without having to refresh my page?
One example, when I am viewing an "All" list view and I open a record from that list that is not currently part of my "Recently Viewed" list view for that object, then navigate to my "Recently Viewed" list, the record is not displayed in the list.  Is it required that I click the refresh button from the list view each time to see the update?  Is this new?


Is it required that I click the refresh button from the list view each time to see the update?

Yes.

Is this new?

No.

In the interface we now call Classic Salesforce, the entire page has to load every time you click on pretty much anything in the UI. Change list views? Page load. Click a record? Page load. Go to edit a record? Page load. You get the idea.
In the Lightning Experience, the page only has to load once. This is why you can quickly switch between a list view and records in a fraction of a second (in most cases). In order to provide an even better experience, this data is cached on the client. Unfortunately, caching has the side effect of having stale data.
This is why each list view shows when it was last updated:

This is to let you know how old the data you're looking at is, and why there's a Refresh (⟳) button. This button updates the view and resets the "last updated" indicator on the list view. As you can see, this is an intentional design choice to maximize performance compared to Classic Salesforce.
If you have the option to switch back to Classic, try moving around in it. It is noticeably slower, since each page has to load, even if you have a blazing-fast Internet connection. Lightning Experience generally feels much faster than Classic, at least under ideal conditions.

Makes sense.  However, the message "Updated a few seconds ago" is not accurate.  I've been staring at my Recently Viewed list and it certainly has NOT been updated in the last few seconds because the list is NOT showing a record I just view previously.  But thank you nonetheless

Going to retract my last statement, the list does seem to now be giving accurate updates now as the minutes progress

Another application on Service Console does not experience this behavior.  Recently Viewed list view updates automatically when toggling b/t All, clicking on a record, toggling back to Recently Viewed.  Record displays without having to click refresh
